# PyQt - How to check is QDialog is visible?

Tags: python, graphics, pyqt, qdialog

I have a problem. I have this code:

```
balls = [Ball() for i in range(1, 10)]
```

So, when I say Ball() this will draw a ball on QDialog. And then when this is done, I am moving the balls around `QDialog` in an infinite loop. I want to say something like *while `QDialog.isVisible()` move them around*.

I don't have any parent dialog or form or any child dialog or form. It's all just about this `QDialog`. I know that it's stupid to do with `QDialog`, but I am not allowed to use anything else than just `QDialog`.

Comment: Is this question just purely about checking the visibility of the dialog, or does it include the part about moving the objects?

Comment: you answered your own question `while MyDialog.isVisible(): pass`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use isVisible from QWidget because QDialog basically inherits QWidget. So you should be able to check the visibility.

```
myDialog = QtGui.QDialog()
isVis = myDialog.isVisible()
```

For more details http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#isVisible