# How to check correct opening the window after the click by button in pytest-qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pytest-qt

I want to test a module in my project, but I have a some problem with it. I don't know how I can check the correct opening of the window after the button click.

I have the windows SelectAddingBookTypeWindow and AddSchoolBookWindow.
I want to check that AddSchoolBookWindow will open after I have clicked on the button called selectBtn.

My current test (I have a problem with the last string because I don't know which method I must use):

```
@pytest.fixture
def open_window(qtbot):
    def _press_button(window):
        widget = window()
        qtbot.addWidget(widget)
        widget.show()
        qtbot.wait_for_window_shown(widget)
        sleep(3)
        return widget
    return _press_button


class TestSelectAddingBookTypeWindow:
    def test_select_schoolbook(self, open_window, qtbot):
        widget = open_window(SelectAddingBookTypeWindow)
        qtbot.mouseClick(widget.schoolbookSelector, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
        qtbot.mouseClick(widget.selectBtn, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
        assert widget.close()
        assert AddSchoolBookWindow.isActiveWindow()
```

My classes:
A. SelectAddingBookTypeWindow

```
class SelectBookTypeWindow(QDialog, Ui_selectBookTypeWindow):
    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self, widget1, widget2):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.selectBtn.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.open_new_window(widget1, widget2))

    @logger.catch
    def open_new_window(self, schoolbook_widget, fictionbook_widget):
        if self.schoolbookSelector.isChecked():
            widget = schoolbook_widget()
        elif self.fictionbookSelector.isChecked():
            widget = fictionbook_widget()
        widget.show()
        self.close()


class SelectAddingBookTypeWindow(SelectBookTypeWindow):
    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(AddSchoolBookWindow, AddFictionBookWindow)
```

B. AddSchoolBookWindow

```
class AddSchoolBookWindow(QDialog, Ui_AddSchoolbookWindow):
    @logger.catch
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.widgets = [
            self.schoolbookAuthor, self.schoolbookTitle, self.schoolbookPublishHouse,
            self.schoolbookPublishYear, self.schoolbookInvoiceNum, self.schoolbookInvoiceDate, self.schoolbookClass,
            self.schoolbookCount, self.schoolbookPrice
        ]
        self.schoolbookSaveBtn.clicked.connect(lambda _: self.save_book())
        self.schoolbookClearBtn.clicked.connect(lambda _: Utils.clear_fields(self.widgets, self.schoolbookInvoiceDate))
        self.schoolbookCancelBtn.clicked.connect(lambda _: self.close())

    @logger.catch
    def save_book(self):
        field_names = Config.COLUMNS['SchoolBook']
        user_data = list(map(lambda x: x.text(), self.widgets))
        book_sum = Utils.calculate_book_sum(user_data)
        user_data.append(str(book_sum))
        book = dict(zip(field_names[1:], user_data))
        db = DatabaseManager(Config.PATHES['TO_DATABASE']['PROD'])
        model = Schoolbook('SchoolBook', db.connection)
        model.insert_book(book)
        logger.success(f'The {book} success add in the database')
        model.model.select()
```

This is a little part of full code but full code doesn't solve with this problem.

Comment: share SelectAddingBookTypeWindow and AddSchoolBookWindow class, provide a [mre]

Comment: I hoped that I can the response in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850240/pyqt-how-to-check-is-qdialog-is-visible/13850761)[this] and using method isVisible() I can solve my problem. I tried to add a string `return widget` in the method called open_new_window in the class SelectBookTypeWindow but my test string `qtbot.mouseClick(widget.selectBtn, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)` returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the widget is not accessible since it is a local variable, I also doubt that the window will be shown as it should be removed a moment later, so to access it I will create a property:

```py
class SelectBookTypeWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_selectBookTypeWindow):
    def __init__(self, widget1, widget2):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.selectBtn.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.open_new_window(widget1, widget2))

        self._selected_window = None

    @property
    def selected_window(self):
        return self._selected_window

    def open_new_window(self, schoolbook_widget, fictionbook_widget):
        if self.schoolbookSelector.isChecked():
            self._selected_window = schoolbook_widget()
        elif self.fictionbookSelector.isChecked():
            self._selected_window = fictionbook_widget()
        if self.selected_window is not None:
            self.selected_window.show()
            self.close()
```

And then in the test you should verify that selected_window is not None and its base class is AddSchoolBookWindow, also avoid using time.sleep(), in the case of the tests use [QTest.qWait()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#qWait)

```py
import pytest
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtTest

from your_package import AddSchoolBookWindow, SelectAddingBookTypeWindow


@pytest.fixture
def open_window(qtbot):
    def callback(window):
        widget = window()
        qtbot.addWidget(widget)
        widget.show()
        qtbot.wait_for_window_shown(widget)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(3 * 1000)
        return widget

    return callback


class TestSelectAddingBookTypeWindow:
    def test_select_schoolbook(self, open_window, qtbot):
        widget = open_window(SelectAddingBookTypeWindow)
        assert widget.isVisible()
        qtbot.mouseClick(widget.schoolbookSelector, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
        qtbot.mouseClick(widget.selectBtn, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
        assert widget.isHidden()
        assert widget.selected_window is not None
        assert isinstance(widget.selected_window, AddSchoolBookWindow)
        assert widget.selected_window.isVisible()
```

Comment: Done. I have a little question yet. This advice will work with testing toolbar elements in the main window?

Comment: @dgonkaries It should work, I have not tested it, try it and tell me if it works or not.